# Spring REST & CORS support not playing well

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, cors

I have exposed an API with Spring REST and is trying to POST data from a standalone jquery code.This is a cross domain request.

My configurations are below

> spring - 3.2.5.RELEASE , jquery - 1.10.2

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", basic);
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

            },
            url: "http://localhost:8080/workflow/workflow-api/human",
            data: '{"id":"1","firstName":"Tito","lastName":"LastName"}',
            crossDomain:true,
            processData: false,
            success: function(msg) {

                console.log( "Login result:"+msg);
            }
    });
```

In Chrome developer console I get the below error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/stockingworkflow/workflow-api/human. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

In web.xml , the CORS filter entry is as below

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.workflow.security.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My filter class as below

```
@Component  
public class CorsFilter  extends OncePerRequestFilter  {


    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationService.class);

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.debug("<-----Inside CORS filter---->");


        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {

            logger.debug("<-----Inside OPTIONS---->");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
        }



        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

I am invoking the jquery ajax request by opening an html file in the browser.The html file is not served by a server.So my URL in the browser is

> file:///C:/Users/3467/Desktop/workflow/index.html

As I have enabled the filter for Cross domain request, ideally the jquery ajax request should have worked.But it says:

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers

In my developer console under "network" I see that OPTIONS GET request was sent by browser and it returned 200 OK. Means it hit the CORS filter.Below is the request & response headers from Chrome developer tools.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/workflow/workflow-api/human
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6,id;q=0.4,ms;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, accept, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.66 Safari/537.36

Response Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1800
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 22 Sep 2014 21:54:29 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I have no idea whats wrong , I have followed many SO and Spring REST blogs for CORS.Don't know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not define the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on client side when sending the request, this header should be added only on the response by the server. You browser will automatically add the `Origin` header specifying the origin domain of the request.

Your filter implementation should also be updated to add CORS headers for both [actual](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests) and [preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests) requests, regardless of the method. You should add CORS headers to the response as soon as a request has an `Origin` header.

Answer (score 2):

JUNE 08, 2015 - breaking news ;) 
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

> The recently released Spring Framework 4.2 RC1 provides first class support for CORS out-of-the-box, giving you an easier and more powerful way to configure it than typical filter based solutions.

If you use Spring Boot please take a look at the last release:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/12/spring-boot-1-3-0-m1-available-now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add the given filter to your web.xml. 
Thereafter, download the cors-filter-2.1.2.jar and java-property-utils-1.9.1 and add them to the lib folder.

This should resolve the issue.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param >

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```